# xunit.net parameterized unit testing: Show red/green for each combination?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, parameterized, xunit.net, parameterized-unit-test

[Parameterized Unit Testing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_testing#Parameterized_Unit_Testing_.28PUT.29) is great when you have X unit test * Y configurations.

I have **3** unit tests, and each must run in **5** particular situations.
I use xUnit.net's `Theory`/`PropertyData` [feature](http://www.tomdupont.net/2012/04/xunit-theory-data-driven-unit-test.html), it works well.

**PROBLEM:** In the Test Runner UI, there is one green/red symbol per unit test, which means **3**.
It makes it difficult to evaluate progress: the symbol is red until ALL configurations work perfectly.
I want **15** symbols, one per unit test * configuration, to know what particular combination is going wrong.

How can I get **15** symbols?
I am OK with using another xunit.net UI.

[image]

**2013 UPDATE**: I ended up switching to NUnit, which has this feature.

Comment: It seems that there is no solution with xunit.net so I asked here about other test frameworks: http://stackoverflow.com/q/13393765

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go upvote [this issue which describes your problem](http://xunit.codeplex.com/workitem/9789).

Comment: +1 That describes my problem, but also emcompasses the notion of debugging a particular configuration, which is probably very tricky to implement. I would be satisfied with just fail/success reports.

Comment: Accepting as it kind of proves that the feature I want is not implemented yet (otherwise they would talk about it at that page).